# How to use boost::algorithm::join with std::vector of objects?

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, c++11, vector

I understand the use of `boost::algorithm::join` on a vector of `std::string` but how do I use it for an `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>`?

I guess I'm looking for some kind of apply function that I can pass in a lambda so I can transform the std::unique_ptr to std::string.

Comment: what are the semantics of `join()` on your `Foo`?

Comment: I'd say you need to build a pseudo container with pseudo iterators to pass as first argument of `boost::algorithm::join`. Personally, I'd consider that as horrible boilerplate code not worth the effort. "Stringify first, then join" will most likely be the easier-to-read way.

Answer (score 1):

Looking are the [source code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/boost/algorithm/string/join.hpp) of `join`, it seems there's no way to do that. The return value must be of `range_value<SequenceSequenceT>::type` type which maps to `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` in your case. You can `std::transform` your `vector` to `std::vector<std::string>`, which is a bit of a waste. Alternatively you could implement your own version of join that applies the transformation itself as it goes.

Comment: Did come across http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3594.html while searching. A proposal to add it to std.